# How to execute sql Query With reducer from Dot Net Application?

Tags: gridgain

I made .Net app which create In Memory DataBase (IMDB) on GG nodes
I would like to execute "select count(*) from ..." on each node against the context of the IMDB which is on that node and return the result to .Net application.

It seems impossible in dot net environment.
Please confirm or suggest solution

Answer (score 0):

The way you should do it now is through GridGain task execution. Create and deploy GridGain task on the server side which will execute the query, and then invoke it from the client side.

In our upcoming releases we are working on updating client APIs to include query execution.

Comment: However, the task sends query to all nodes and each is returning the same results. The problem is that the query is accessing ALL IMDB. How to restrict query execution for just local local segment IMDB?

Comment: @ValK From your GridTask.map() method return your job mapped to local node only.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with GridGain 6.2.0-rc2 release GridGain you can execute SQL, SCAN, or TEXT queries directly form .NET or C++ clients.

The example of .NET queries is available with enterprise version download: http://www.gridgain.com/download/